# URL subdomain routing in ASP.NET 4.0 (not MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I want to do URL routing like a subdomain.

For example, say my website is website.com. I want to do URL rewriting like

```
client1.website.com,
client2.website.com,
client3.website.com,
clientN.website.com
```

In my website there is a list of clients. Whenever I click on a client my URL looks like this:

```
website.com/client.aspx?client=client1
website.com/client.aspx?client=client2
website.com/client.aspx?client=client3
website.com/client.aspx?client=clientN
```

Now i want the URL rewriting to make it look like this:

```
client1.website.com
client2.website.com
client3.website.com
clientN.website.com
```

Also, whenever one client is registered, that client should be able to directly open site.

Comment: Routing is part of core ASP.NET.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx